# List Formatting in Word - Variable Format for Empty Items

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm preparing a legal document with numbered paragraphs.

Sometimes there is text that accompanies a first level item, other times there is only text relating to the second level item. No matter what I try using numbered or multi-level lists I end up with something like this.

```
    12. This is a paragraph filled with legal jargon, but has been made 
        more readable using subheadings. It is easy to make a list 
        like this, which improves:
        a) readability;
        b) reliability; and
        c) reference-ability.
    13. I haven't figured out how to do the tasks referred to in
        sub-paragraphs 14(a)&(b).
    14. a) There is no text that is associated with 14, just text 
           associated with subparagraphs.
        b) I really don't want use tabs and manually number things.
        c) It ends up looking like this:
           | 14.
           |     a) There is no text ....
        d) The text cited in sub-paragraph (c) is ugly. How can I get
           rid of that paragraph break?
```

How can I get this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LISTNUM field for your (a) level numbering when it is on the same line as 1. numbering.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. After going to the `Insert::Field` menu and selecting `ListNum`, I enabled the `\l` field after pressing the options button. I added the number I needed, and the result was `LISTNUM \l 2`. I then adjusted the paragraph indent and added a tab stop at the appropriate place.